# store string array and reference it

Tags: java, android

I am looking for an easy way to store these array elements directly to my string resource

```java
   private static final String[] listCategory = new String[]{"Default", "Personal", "shopping", "Wishlist", "computer Programming", "work"};
```

Comment: Typically it would happen the other way around, namely you would be populating a Java string array using a resource file.  Why do you have this requirement?

Comment: Dear @nonso - couldn't understand your requirement. Are you looking this array to concat or convert to 1 string?

Comment: The code written above is one of the easiest possible way of string assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. create arrays.xml in values folder

   ```
   <string-array name="array_name">
   <item>A</item>
   <item>B</item>
   <item>C</item>
   <item>D</item>
   ```
2. You can get this array from code bellow

   String[] arr = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array_name);

Comment: thank you very much this was exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
 String[] branch = {"Default", "Personal", "shopping", "Wishlist", "computer Programming", "work"};
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<string name="default">Default</string>
<string name="personal">Personal</string>

<string-array name="strings">
    <item>@string/default</item>
    <item>@string/personal</item>
</string-array>
```